# Combine whitelist and blacklist in java regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I am having problems constructing a regex that will allow the full range of UTF-8 characters with the exception of 2 characters: '_' and '?'

So the whitelist is: ^[\u0000-\uFFFF]
and the blacklist is: ^[^_%]

I need to combine these into one expression.

I have tried the following code, but does not work the way I had hoped:

```
    String input = "this";
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("^[\u0000-\uFFFF]+$ | ^[^_%]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    boolean result = m.matches();
    System.out.println(result);
```

input: this
actual output: false
desired output: true

Comment: updated code, returns false for valid input

Comment: You should provide an example of input and desired ouput.

Comment: From this document:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, you could try this:    [a-z&&[^m-p]] a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction).  A full range of characters, except other range.

Comment: You can try this - `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?!.*[_%])[\u0000-\uFFFF]+");`

Comment: thanks Jose Luis, I needed to nest the expression.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry no to help.  :-)

Comment: I meant to say thanks for your help Jose Luis, your solution works and the link helped me understand

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**character class intersections/subtractions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) in Java regex to restrict a "generic" character class.

> The character class `[a-z&&[^aeiuo]]` matches a single letter that is not a vowel. In other words: it matches a single consonant.

Use

```
"^[\u0000-\uFFFF&&[^_%]]+$"
```

to match all the Unicode characters except `_` and `%`.

More about character class intersections/subtractions available in Java regex, see [*The Java™ Tutorials: Character Classes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

A test at the [OCPSoft Visual Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) showing there is no match when a `%` is added to the string:

[image]

And the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UqB1sB):

```
String input = "this";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\u0000-\uFFFF&&[^_%]]+"); // No anchors because `matches()` is used
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
boolean result = m.matches();
System.out.println(result); // => true
```

Comment: plus 1 nice solution using intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code to exclude some of characters from a range using [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that actually do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

Sample code: (exclude `m` and `n` from range `a-z`)

```
    String str = "abcdmnxyz";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?![mn])[a-z]");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

output:

```
a b c d x y z
```

In the same way you can do it.

Regex explanation `(?![mn])[a-z]`

```
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:   
    [mn]                     any character of: 'm', 'n' 
  )                        end of look-ahead    
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
```

---

You can divide the whole range in sub-ranges and can solve the above problem with `([a-l]|[o-z])` or `[a-lo-z]` regex also.

Comment: There is a better way using character set intersection.

Comment: Please can you add it as answer so that I can also learn it. There can be other ways as well like `([a-l]|[o-z])`

Comment: Your solution is good to use in JavaScript and Python `re`. If the solution must be portable between Java, Python and JS, this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the spaces either side of the pipe.

Neither of

```
" ^.*"
".*$ "
```

will match anything, because nothing appears before start or after end.

This has a chance:

```
^[\u0000-\uFFFF]+$|^[^_%]
```